# How does Attribute Inheritance in C++ Work?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Suppose you wanted to reproduce the following Python snippet:

```
class Base:
    name = "base"

    def announce(self):
        print(self.name)

class Derived(Base):
    name = "derived"

Base().announce()
Derived().announce()
```

... which would output:

```
"base"
"derived"
```

Initially, you may be inclined to write something like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Base {
    std::string name = "base";
    void announce() {
        std::cout << name << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    std::string name = "movie";
};

int main() {
    Base().announce();
    Derived().announce();
    return 0;
}
```

But here `Derived.name` simply shadows `Base.name`. Calling `Derived.announce()` references `Base.name` and prints "base".

Is there any way to implement this behaviour? Ideally without class templates if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ doesn't work like Python (which isn't surprising, they are two very different languages after all), and member variables defined in an inherited class really defines a new variable that is unrelated to the variables of the parent class.

One possible solution is to create a second (possibly protected) `Base` constructor which takes the `name` as an argument, and then the `Derived` class can use it to initialize the member:

```
struct Base {
    Base() = default;  // A defaulted default constructor

    std::string name = "base";
    void announce() {
        std::cout << name << std::endl;
    }

protected:
    explicit Base(std::string name)
        : name{ std::move(name) }  // Initialize the member
    {
    }
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    Derived()
        : Base("movie")  // Initialize the base class using the special constructor
    {
    }
};
```

The default `Base` default constructor is needed, because if you declare another constructor the compiler won't automatically generate a default constructor for you.

Comment: Wow. I don't see your answer for 30-some odd minutes, write and post a near duplicate, and then your answer pops up. Wonder what I did to set off that bizarro chain of events.

Comment: @user4581301 Sorry, my time-machine was acting up again... :)