# Initializing a member in an inherited class with different value of base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, member-initialization

Lets say I have an `Entity` class with the variable `x` and it is defined as `0` in that class.

Well then I make a derived class `Player` but I want the `Player`'s inherited `x` by default to be `1` and not `0`, so that every `Player` I create has `x` be `1` by default.

Is this possible?

And if it is, how can I do it?

Comment: Why not initialize the member to 1 in player's constructor?

Comment: please, show your code, or at least an example

Comment: Inspiration (almost duplicate): [How does Attribute Inheritance in C++ Work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61314511/how-does-attribute-inheritance-in-c-work)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible, I've read the comments and I gather you want the base member to be private, one option is to inherit base class constructor.

[**Classes** Sample 1](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3iF6KOfdjnDj4RUL)

```
class Entity{
private:
    int x;
public:
    Entity(int i = 0) : x(i) {} //initialize x to 0
    int getX() {return x;}
};

class Player: public Entity{
public:
    Player() : Entity(1) {}   //inherit base class constructor initializing x to 1
};
```

This implementation has a potential weakness, it allows for the construction of objects initializing `x`. If you do not want this you can have a protected constructor that allows derived classes to specify the member value, preventing the construction of objects that can initialize `x`.

[**Classes** Sample 2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BeC3GnJMf8IA8q72)

```
class Entity {    
    int x = 0;    
public:
    Entity() = default; //default construtor
    int getX(){return x;}

protected:
    Entity(int i) : x(i) {} //protected constructor, 
};

class Player : public Entity {
public:
    Player() : Entity(1) {}
};
```

**Usage**

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{   
    Entity e;
    cout << e.getX() << endl;

    Player p;
    cout << p.getX();

    return 0;
}
```

Deppending on the compexity of your classes you might also make the protected construtor [explicit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit)

**Output**

```
0
1
```

Note that this is a very simplified version, you should observe the rules of class construction like for instance [The rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Answer (score 1):

```
class Entity {
  private:
    int x;
  public:
    Entity() : x(0)
  {}
    void set_x(int y){
      x = y;
    }
    int get_x(){
      return x;
    }

};

class Player : public Entity {
  public:
    Player() 
    {
      set_x(1);
    }
};
```

Comment: what is the point of "player()" under public? can I not simply do x=1 in the player class without it being within that?

Comment: @user4581301 There can be lots of corner cases, and I think a general design is OK for the author of this question.

Comment: @Aravash I don't think so. The assignment should take place when the construction of the Player class happens.